# How to access a two dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, nlp

I have a response text from an NLP API which look like this.
[[0.9999999999999995,"doc1","doc1"]]
There is no proper documentation for this and so i am finding it difficult to access the real number from the text programmatically without tokenizing the string.
Can someone help me out please.

Comment: You could use a JSON parser for it.

Comment: I tried this:             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result.asJsonString());
            System.out.println(json.toString());  but i got this error:  A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: Assuming that the object that the NLP API returns is a `String`, are you sure that it will always maintain the same structure?

Comment: Yes the structure is always the same. Here is the docs https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/PetiteProgrammer/TextSimilarity/docs I am using the following library from Json.org:  json-20160810.jar

Comment: Use `JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result.asJsonString());` if you're using that library from Json.org.

Comment: In my observation, this response is not a json format:[[0.9999999999999994,"doc1","doc1"]] And even though i parse it to jsonarry object, i could not  get an item with is code :) JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

Answer (score 1):

You will need a couple of response classes like

```
class NLPResponse {
    private long firstParam; //Give it a proper name
    private String secondParam;
    private String thirdParam;

    //Constructor(s), getters and setters
}

class NLPResponseArrayWrapper {
    private ArrayList<NLPResponse> arrayWrapper = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructor(s), getters and setters
}
```

Then you can use `Gson` to parse the json and make an object out of it. You can use something like this where you are getting the response from `nlp api`.

```
NLPResponseArrayWrapper response = gson.fromJson(JSON_IN_API_RESPOSE, NLPResponseArrayWrapper.class);
doSomething(response.getArrayWrapper().get(0).getFirstParam());
```

[Here](https://github.com/google/gson) is how you can use `Gson` in your project.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I did just as you said but i think there is a format issue. I have this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path

Comment: Maybe the json you posted in the question is not 100% same as the json returned by API. Can you please check again?

Comment: If may understand a json format, is looks like this:[{"lgvt_area_id":"Fufore","state_id":"Adamawa"},{"lgvt_area_id":"Guyuk","state_id":"Adamawa"},{"lgvt_area_id":"Demsa","state_id":"Adamawa"},{"lgvt_area_id":"Ganye","state_id":"Adamawa"}] The response from nlp api looks more of a multi-dimensional array :) [[0.9999999999999995,"doc1","doc1"]]  The only confusion there is the combination  double and  string in one array as values.